# Get root url of disk PHP

Tags: php, path

How can I get the root of the disk on my server? Like for example in windows I would like to get into the root of the drive `C:/` but I want my code to be dynamic if we ever decide to use linux.

I have tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but it only returns the root folder of the project.

Is there any way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Why do you need to root of the disk?  You may not have access form your web site as permissions may restrict access outside of the web root directory.

Comment: `define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manually construct that / worry about it.

A better approach is to have a constant in your project that marks the path to it from the root.

To do this you can do something like

`define('PROJECT_ROOT', __DIR__);`

See more about `__DIR__` here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Basically this takes care of the OS context for you so if your project is on windows it'll be `C:\...` and on Linux based systems just `/...`

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Thanks very much! will accept the answer in 3mins